# Delete Post after a month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

Ok, I have a `useInterval` (custom hook) that will delete a document from firestore after a given time is milliseconds. It works fine if I set it to 10 seconds, 1 minute.

However, when I set it to delete the document a month after it was created, it looks like it creates the document and gets deleted right away.

How can I set my interval to delete the document after a month from when it was created?

```js
 const docRef = firestore.doc(`posts/${id}`)
  const deleDoc = () => docRef.delete();


  //******************************************************************* */
  //? Deleting post after a month(time managed in milliseconds)
  const now = createdAt.seconds * 1000; 
  const monthFromNow = 2628000000;
  const then = now + monthFromNow;
  const timeLeft = then - Date.now();

  //?custom hook
  useInterval(() => {
    docRef.delete();
  }, timeLeft);
```

Comment: either use local storage or store the creation date on the server

Comment: will this not work on firebase's firestore?

Comment: sorry, not familiar with firebase

Answer (score 0):

You can create a task which hits one of your cloud function endpoint using [Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler). You can set it to hit the API every 1 min.

In the API you can pull up all the documents which are older than 1 month and delete them using the above logic.